# MappedByteBuffer Memory Usage

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a program that runs for 12+ hours before it gets a restart. The program is a minecraft server so it can not be really restarted that often.

Anyway about every 25-35 minutes a file is being read that is 42-67mb in size. I use RandomAccessFile and a MappedByteBuffer to read the file into an ObjectInputStream.

The issue is every time the file is read the memory usage goes up by 100-300mb which will eventually cause a OOM because it never gets garbage collected. I currently am using VisualVM to debug it and I only see the ram usage increase when the file is read.

I have added

```
((DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner().clean();
```

but it does not seem to get the VM to garbage collect.

Answer (score 3):

The speed benefit of a mapped buffer over a random access file was about 20% when I measured it in about 2003. I would be surprised if it has increased since, and I would also be surprised if it was as high for sequential access. Given the risk of OOME, it's not worth it. Use an ObjectInputStream around a BufferedInputStream around a FileInputStream.

Comment: Well I did have that before but it caused issues as it took much longer to load the file which caused lag issues for the players.

Comment: Opps actually that is not what I did. Let me try that and see where it goes.